# No Reverse Match when using Slugify

Tags: python, django

Model field:

```
url_slug = models.SlugField(default='', max_length=200, null=False)
```

Model methods:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    new_kwargs = {
        'pk': self.pk,
        'url_slug': self.url_slug
    }
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs=new_kwargs)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    value = self.title
    self.url_slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py:

```
path('blogs/<str:url_slug>-<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

template url:

```
"{% url 'post-detail' blog.url_slug|slugify blog.pk %}"
```

Error:

```
Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '(56,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blogs\\/(?P<url_slug>[^/]+)\\-(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

Can't figure out what the issue is here?

Edit:

It may be worth noting that I created the slugify method after several model objects were already created, however I went back and added `url_slug` fields for all of them.

Comment: Why are you using `|` in `"{% url 'post-detail' blog.url_slug|slugify blog.pk %}" `?

Comment: An attempt to address the error. With or without it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        new_kwargs = {
        'slug': self.url_slug,
        'pk': self.pk
    }
```

urls:

`path('blogs/<slug:slug>-<int:pk>', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),`

Template href:

`"{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}"`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is, you should use the model method instead. like

```
"{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}"
```

since you have already defined it. Make sure not to call the method in template as it will be called automatically.